# Importing database into zeppelin on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

When I import the table of data with

```
val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM newsletter.newsletter_delivery where newsletter_delivery.ndi_divisione_id = 61" ).show
```

I see (extract of a column):

+-------------------------+

|ndi_committente_id|

|null|

|null|

|null|

....
in words a table that is divided by |.

At the moment I am parsing this enormous string and inputting the data into a dataframe which is slow since the data is very big. I was wondering if there was a way to get the data from aws and directly load it into a spark dataframe or pyspark dataframe.

Comment: When you say "get the data from aws" is this mean that you want to load from S3?

Comment: exactly, I apologise for not mentioning that before.